# I am facing problem chaining the async code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to execute allCountryData and return a promise its working fine but after allCountryData is done executing I want to perform a operation on that returned data / or allCountryDataArray and store the highest values in arrayOfHighestCases

Note I can't chain the other login in allCountryData.

Please help let me know if you need any more details

```
export const allCountryDataArray = [];
export const arrayOfHighestCases = [];

const allCountryData = async () => {
  sendHTTP()
    .then((res) => {
      return res.response;
    })
    .then((res) => {
      allCountryDataArray.push(...res);
      return allCountryDataArray;
    });
  return await allCountryDataArray;

  // Highest Cases
};
```

The code is below is not working

```
const highestCasesData = async () => {
  // const allCountryDataArrayy = await allCountryData();
  // allCountryData()
  // .then((data) => {
  //   console.log(arrayOfHighestCases[0]);
  // })
  // .then((res) => {
  const np = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res(allCountryData());
  });

  return np.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    const arrayofHigh = allCountryDataArray.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.cases.total < b.cases.total) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a.cases.total > b.cases.total) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    console.log(arrayofHigh);
    const slicedArray = arrayofHigh.slice(0, 6);
    for (const eachHighCase of slicedArray) {
      arrayOfHighestCases.push(eachHighCase);
    }
    console.log(arrayOfHighestCases);
    return arrayOfHighestCases;
  });

  // });
};
highestCasesData();
```

Comment: `return await allCountryDataArray` doesn’t make sense: `allCountryDataArray` isn’t a Promise. The promise chain starting with `sendHTTP` is discarded and the `return` executes before `sendHTTP` et al. are finished. Did you mean `return sendHTTP(`…`)`…?

Comment: Your `np` is also nonsense, if fixed, `allCountryData()` returns a Promise, so wrapping it in one is not necessary. There's also no need to `await` something in a function that you're passing to `.then()`, just return the Promise.

Comment: Got it I removed the np and returned sendHTTP it working now Thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 2):

Filling global arrays with async data is a way into timing conflicts. Bugs where the data ain't there, except when you look it is there and yet another question here on my SO about "Why can't my code access data? When I check in the console everything looks fine, but my code ain't working."

If you want to store something, store Promises of these arrays or [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the functions.

```
const allCountryData = async () => {
  const res = await sendHTTP();
  return res.response;
};

const highestCasesData = async () => {
  const allCountryDataArray = await allCountryData();

  return allCountryDataArray
    .slice()  // make a copy, don't mutate the original array
    .sort((a, b) => b.cases.total - a.cases.total)  // sort it by total cases DESC
    .slice(0, 6); // take the first 6 items with the highest total cases
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working please let me know if I can make some more improvements

```
const allCountryData = async () => {
  return sendHTTP()
    .then((res) => {
      return res.response;
    })
    .then((res) => {
      allCountryDataArray.push(...res);
      return allCountryDataArray;
    });

  // Highest Cases
};

const highestCasesData = async () => {

  return allCountryData().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    const arrayofHigh = allCountryDataArray.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.cases.total < b.cases.total) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a.cases.total > b.cases.total) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    console.log(arrayofHigh);
    const slicedArray = arrayofHigh.slice(0, 6);
    for (const eachHighCase of slicedArray) {
      arrayOfHighestCases.push(eachHighCase);
    }
    console.log(arrayOfHighestCases);
    return arrayOfHighestCases;
  });

};
highestCasesData();
```

Comment: Use `async` only when you use `await` instead of `then`